# Copying a portion of a list to a new list

Tags: c#, list, string

Hey all.  Is there a way to copy only a portion of a single (or better yet, a two) dimensional list of strings into a new temporary list of strings?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Even though LINQ does make this easy and more general than just lists (using `Skip` and `Take`), `List<T>` has the [`GetRange`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/21k0e39c.aspx) method which makes it a breeze:

```
List<string> newList = oldList.GetRange(index, count);
```

(Where `index` is the index of the first element to copy, and `count` is how many items to copy.)

When you say "two dimensional list of strings" - do you mean an array? If so, do you mean a jagged array (`string[][]`) or a rectangular array (`string[,]`)?

Comment: This is a shallow copy of the list (This does not copy the list to new list, it has the references). So you have to be careful

Comment: @Diode: It copies the contents of the list to the new list - the contents of the list *are* string references. You're right that it's a shallow copy, but as strings are immutable, a shallow copy is almost indistinguishable from a deep copy anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I get the question, but I would look at the **Array.Copy** function (**if by lists of strings you're referring to arrays**)

Here is an example using C# in the .NET 2.0 Framework:

```
String[] listOfStrings = new String[7] 
                              {"abc","def","ghi","jkl","mno","pqr","stu"};
String[] newListOfStrings = new String[3];

// copy the three strings starting with "ghi" 
Array.Copy(listOfStrings, 2, newListOfStrings, 0, 3);

// newListOfStrings will now contains {"ghi","jkl","mno"}
```

Answer (score -1):

FindAll will let you write a Predicate to determine which strings to copy:

```
List<string> list = new List<string>();
list.Add("one");
list.Add("two");
list.Add("three");

List<string> copyList = list.FindAll(
    s => s.Length >= 5
);

copyList.ForEach(s => Console.WriteLine(s));
```

This prints out "three", because it is 5 or more characters long.  The others are ignored.